# How do I retrieve a data type of tinyint from MySQL in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, tinyint

So in C# whenever I retrieved a tinyint from my MSSQL database I used the following cast.

```
(int)(byte)reader["MyField"];
```

However, that cast doesn't seem to work in MySQL.

**What I have tried**

```
(byte)reader["MyField"];
```

and just

```
(int)reader["MyField"];
```

**Edit 1**

**Exception**

```
The specified cast is not valid.
```

**Edit 2**

This is the data type.

```
{Name = "SByte" FullName = "System.SByte"}
```

Comment: Have you tried `reader["MyField"] + 0;`?

Comment: @Hans That won't compile: the expression is typed `object + int` there, for which there is no matching `+` operator.

Comment: Have you tried `int.Parse(reader["MyField"].ToString());`?

Comment: @Hans That would actually work ... but why? ;-)

Comment: The two methods I've described are the laziest ways to program between different data types and actually get values back. The first one will automatically invoke any implicit cast that object to `byte`,`int`,`double`,`float`,or `long`, which can be then cast to int. The second one physically takes the `ToString()` of the object, which, if correctly implemented for the type of your object, should return a string of digits which `int.Parse` should be able to read as an `int`. These methods require no knowledge of what the datatypes are and instead use (perhaps inefficient) type specific methods.

Comment: And yes, the last one works for `Nullable<T>` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that due to casting and explicit operators:

`(byte)objectExpression` is is not the same as `(byte)sbyteExpression`.

The first is a [direct] *cast* which fails because the real object type is `sbyte` and not `byte`. The latter will perform a *conversion* that just happens to use a explicit operator (an "Explicit Conversion") with syntax that, unfortunately, still *looks* like a [direct] *cast* as per above. Here is an example of it failing sans-database:

```
var obj = (object)(sbyte)0;
var i1 = (int)(sbyte)obj;  // okay: object (cast)-> sbyte (conversion)-> int
var i2 = (int)obj;         // fail: sbyte (cast)-> int (but sbyte is not int!)
```

Either use an `(sbyte)objectExpression` cast which is valid for the real object type, or `Convert.ToInt32(objectExpression)` which takes an `object` and does some magic to *convert* it to an int. (Using `Convert.ToByte` could throw an exception on overflow.)

Happy coding!

Comment: Correct! gotta wait 6 minutes.

Comment: +1, seriously this had bitten me always and left clueless, till i read this answer!

Answer (score 10):

To determine the proper type, look at the value of

```
reader["MyField"].GetType()
```

in the debugger.

Comment: Your a genius! Let me look real quick

Comment: (A great comment... but it doesn't answer the "how to" as and of itself...)

Comment: I try to help people help themselves.

Comment: @webdad3 it provides a clear method to find out how the code should look like. The OP must do a tiny step in addition to this to solve the problem.

Comment: VS2017: "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated "

Comment: @quilkin that message can happen when the debugger refuses to evaluate an expression. The actual program is fine.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to let the system work against itself?
The DataReader class provides features for getting the correct type of value:

```
reader.GetInt32("id");
reader.GetByte("MyByteField");
```

This way the Reader provides you with the type you expect.